# Как запускать одну программу на python 2,7 под разными пользователями windows

Tags: python, windows, users

Здравствуйте. Есть программа на python 2.7 которая работает в цикле, возникла проблема в следующем, при блокировке компьютера пользователем, программа продолжает работать и по этому если зайти с другого пользователя то программа не откроется, так как процесс уже запущен. Помогите решить такого рода проблему.

Подскажите как в python 2.7 написать скрипт, который будет добавлять задачи, в планировщик задач windows. Либо как сделать, что бы при блокировки компьютера(win+l), процесс программы закрывался, а при разблокировке запускался.

Comment: А почему бы просто не проверить, что тот процесс под другим пользователем и запустить ещё один под текущим?

Comment: Нужно как то завершать процесс, потому что программа использует COM port и можно только установить одно соединение с ним)